# CRM 2016 + Currency is required if a value exists

Tags: dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I have javascript on my form wherein onchange of a field, currency is set.

For eg i have a field named 'Field1', on change of a value in 'Field1', currency is set and an another money field (say price) is set based on the currency selected.

So the scenario is, when the value from Field1 is removed, currency and price both are set to blank,after then if a value is selected in Field1, eventhough the currency is set it throws an error "Currency is required if a value exists". My Assumption is it throws the error because i am trying to set the price field also after setting the currency.

Below is the code used to set currency.

```
                var arrLookupData = new Array();
                var objLookupItem = new Object();
                objLookupItem.typename = "transactioncurrency";
                objLookupItem.id = varray.id;
                objLookupItem.name = varray.name;
                arrLookupData[0] = objLookupItem;
                Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").setValue(arrLookupData);
              Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").fireOnChange();

//Some code
 Xrm.Page.getAttribute("core_price").setValue(value);
```

Kindly suggest.

Comment: What does the code look like ?

Comment: Did you verify after setting the currency in user settings?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you invoke `fireOnChange` after you set values in fields from Javascript, otherwise the form won't "see" the new data.

Your code would become:

```
var arrLookupData = new Array();
//
// omitted
//
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").setValue(arrLookupData);
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("transactioncurrencyid").fireOnChange();
```

Comment: i tried setting the money field on change of currency by using fireOnchange but still getting the same error

Comment: I added a code sample based on your code to clarify what I mean, is this what you tried ?

Comment: Hi yes i added the same line of code d way the way you showed (Updated the code..please see) and created a separate function to set price field and called this function onchange of currency.But it threw the same error